# Persist Elastic/Kibana db/config running from docker?

Tags: database, docker, elasticsearch, kibana, persist

How can I persist Elastic search database and Kibana configuration if I start both of them from docker images :

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.2

docker run -p 5601:5601 -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.2
```

---

I know I have to use 'docker-volumes', but I was wondering if somebody had a recipe for making the stock images work.

Answer (score -1):

To Get Persistence Docker Container Running at backend you need to add Detached flag along with docker run command.

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.2

docker run -d -p 5601:5601 -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.2
```

if you want to make it more secure and reliable you can use your own data volume in case if docker container stops you don't lose your data.

By applying given flag.

> -v host/source:path/container

Further, Read [Dcoker Dcoumentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached-vs-foreground)